# Dental sealant - what happens when they expire?

Tags: dentistry

I've read Wikipedia and used Web search for like after 10 years,  expiration but found only what percentage remains intact,  no need to remove prematurely,  etc.

My question is if sealant is removed and/or wear off - do teeth under it are like natural or teeth become lacking some natural protection due to sealing procedure? I've read procedure include acid application,  maybe it's optional?  What is way to seal w/out negative effect on emanel/dentin of tooth?